# Inline SVGs not showing only on Firefox

Tags: svg, firefox

I get my SVGs on IcoMoon and the way I integrate them is the following:

I have a "sprite.svg" file in my project that contains all "symbols", e.g:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-search" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M31.008 27.231l-7.58-6.447c-0.784-0.705-1.622-1.029-2.299-0.998 1.789-2.096 2.87-4.815 2.87-7.787 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12s-12 5.373-12 12 5.373 12 12 12c2.972 0 5.691-1.081 7.787-2.87-0.031 0.677 0.293 1.515 0.998 2.299l6.447 7.58c1.104 1.226 2.907 1.33 4.007 0.23s0.997-2.903-0.23-4.007zM12 20c-4.418 0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8 8-8 8 3.582 8 8-3.582 8-8 8z"></path>
</symbol>
<symbol id="icon-facebook" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M19 6h5v-6h-5c-3.86 0-7 3.14-7 7v3h-4v6h4v16h6v-16h5l1-6h-6v-3c0-0.542 0.458-1 1-1z"></path>
</symbol>
    ... and so on
</defs>
</svg>
```

Then in my HTML:

```
<svg class="icon icon-twitter">
<use xlink:href="sprite.svg#icon-twitter"></use>
</svg>
```

Then I set the height/width/color with CSS

```
    .icon {
      fill: $color-white;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
    }
```

It works everywhere EXCEPT on Firefox which won't show any of my SVGs. Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT:** the SVGs are in the DOM alright and when I hover on them with the inspector it shows the space they take, they just don't display

[image]

**EDIT 2:** I made it to work using the traditionnal way I guess, i.e not using the sprite.svg file:

```
     <svg class="icon icon-chevron-down--filter-by"  viewBox="0 0 20 20" >
              <path d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z"></path>
     </svg>
```

Firefox now recognizes the icons but I would still prefer just using `<use xlink:href="sprite.svg#icon-search"></use>` instead of passing the whole path each time... If you guys have a solution it's cool, otherwise, well, at least it works

Comment: I dumped the whole symbol part, wrote a Web Component (supported in all modern browsers), now usage is: ``<svg-icon is="chevron-down"></svg-icon>`` See: https://iconmeister.github.io/ Copy/paste the IcoMoon viewBox width as ``box:value`` and ``d-``paths and it will work

Comment: In your example, you have set the fill colour to white, and have placed it on a white background.  On the basis of that, Firefox is rendering it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I actually had an unclosed `<symbol>` tag in my sprite.svg file that was screwing everything up and that's the reason most of my SVGs were not showing